# How can I remotely debug Django application?

Tags: python, django, debugging

I created a Django application, it works fine on my machine.
After that I checked out it at the test server but something doesn't work. 
How can I  debug it?
Is it possible to do it using PyDev Eclipse plugin or maybe are there some other ways?
In the best case I would like to use "step into", "step over", "step out" but if it is not possible, simple logging is also OK.

**UPDATE:** 
On my machine it runs with `./manage.py runserver` but on the test machine it runs with Apache+mod_wsgi

Comment: Try pycharm. I was please with its features(remote debugging included).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a HOWTO for debugging application deployed via mod_wsgi:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/DebuggingTechniques

Do you have root access to test machine? That would make it much easier. You can stop the Apache service and bring it up in a single process mode for debugging.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the link, I'll take a look at it now. Yes I have an access to test machine, but the OS on my machine is Linux and on the test machine is Windows Server

Comment: How can I bring it up in a single process?

Comment: Given that its Windows, there should be an option of "Start Apache in console"

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to just set `DEBUG = True` for a while, that should do for most problems. If you are on production and thus don't want to change that setting because of security concerns, I would recommend using [sentry](https://github.com/dcramer/django-sentry) ([screenshot](https://assets0.github.com/img/ab12bd91d2040a23614a2cbba25dc4c0077898ec?repo=&url=http://dl.dropbox.com/u/116385/sentry2.jpg&path=)), a very nice dashboard-like overview of errors and problems that occurred on your Django site.

Both solutions won't give you line-by-line debugging, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I would say by using https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions - a plugin that adds lots of functionality to django. One is the ./manage.py runserver_plus that adds a terminal to the server's error message (and more) whenever something goes wrong. It's ideal for debugging.

Not sure how to use it with wsgi but a quick search should find several results.